# Boundary of a double integral using substitution

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

Can someone help me out and explain how to find the boundary I need in order to solve the following double integral, I posted below what I did so far but I am stuck here and I don't know if it's even correct what I did until now. Evaluating the integral is not needed, I just want to learn how to find the boundary.

$$ \int \int _D\frac{yln\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{x^2}dxdy$$ $where$ $D:\:1\le x^2+y^2\le e^2;$ $2x\le y\le x\le 0$

I have done the following so far:

$x^2+y^2=1$ circle with the center O(0,0) and R=1

$x^2+y^2=e^2$ circle with the center O(0,0) and R=e

$2x=y$ first  bisector

$x=0$ at Oy  with $x\le 0$ in $\left[\frac{\pi }{2},\pi \right]$ and $\left[\pi ,\frac{3\pi \:}{2}\right]$

$$T:D'\rightarrow D,T:x=\delta cos\theta ,y=\delta sin\theta, \delta \in \left[1,e\right],  \theta \in \left[\frac{5\pi }{4} ,\frac{3\pi }{2}\right]$$

I chose $D'=\left[1,e\right]$x$\left[\frac{5\pi }{4} ,\frac{3\pi }{2}\right]$ but i am not sure if it's the right boundary or not especially on the 2nd bracket, I am almost certain one of them is $\frac{3\pi }{2}$ but the other one I am not sure.

edit: added the desmos
[image]

Comment: your region is bounded between two lines. Right ?why you just considered one

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, did you mean on the second inequality that i should've had $2x=y, x=y, x=0$? I wasn't sure if this is how you split the inequality but even with this I am not sure if the 2nd boundary is correct, at least the 1st unit.

Comment: Oh, $x\leq 0$. This is why. but  from where you got $\frac{5\pi}{4}$?

Comment: I saw your comment and I thought I forgot to add x=y and since I added it I saw it goes through $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ so I thought it's just $sin\left(\frac{5\pi }{4}\right)$

Comment: $$\theta \in \left[\frac{5\pi }{4} , \pi + tan^{-1}{(2)}\right]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x = r \cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$. Bounds of $\theta$ is given by line $y = x$ and $y = 2x$

$r \cos\theta = r\sin\theta \implies \theta = \frac{5 \pi}{4}$ and that is one of the bounds you correctly found.

$2 r \cos\theta = r\sin\theta \implies \theta = (\pi + \arctan 2)$  is the other bound.

So bounds are $1 \leq r \leq e, \frac{5 \pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq (\pi + \arctan 2)$

Comment: Math lover, this is correct

Comment: Thanks again, you also helped me in the past I appreciate!

Comment: You are welcome.